# Removing App ID from Developer Connection

Tags: iphone, iphone-developer-program, app-id

How do I remove an App ID from the developer program portal area?  I mistakenly added a couple of app id's under the wrong login and would like to remove them, but I am not seeing a way to do so.

Comment: My problem is that I made a mistake with my App bundle name and so I created another one... Now they have the same name and I don't know which one to choose when creating a profile!

Comment: Apparently you can now delete App ids, a very welcome change!

Comment: UPDATE: Now its possible to delete app id.

Comment: @jowie You can simply rename the App IDs. The "Name" field is merely descriptive and can be edited any time. Change the unwanted ones from "Whatever" to "IGNORE Whatever".

Comment: How can I change app id on developer.apple.com ?

Comment: Can we delete multiple APPID at once I know its not possible from the  portal but any other way, i have 400+ and its pain when need to manually create a profile to keep self organised and search one

Answer (score 110):

**Update**: You can now remove an App ID (as noted by @Guru in the comments).

In the past, this was not possible: I had the same problem, and the folks at Apple replied that they will leave all of the App ID you create associated to your login, to keep track of a sort of history related to your login.

It seems that they finally changed idea about.

Comment: okay, they don't want them to be deleted. But why don't they let us RENAME them or DISABLE them, or stop us creating two with the same name?

Comment: agreed!!! here I am about to submit to the app store and I have to take a 50/50 chance on which to use. Hah!

Comment: @BradGoss : Actually, you do not have to take a 50/50 chance. As long as you assign the Bundle Identifier using reverse domain strings, theres no reason why there should ever be a ID that gets rejected. For example you can use com.mycompany.legalEntity.country.appName
Since it is highly unlikely that the same company name produces the exact same app in the same country, you'll never be rejected.

Comment: Now its possible to delete app ID :)

Comment: @SteveCav Apple does indeed let you change the "Name" field of your App ID. As of today 2013-07-31, I did so myself. Click the App ID row to see a detail panel, click the "Edit" button found at bottom.

Comment: I cannot delete a certain app id as of today.

Comment: how do you delete it?

Comment: The ability to delete app IDs seems to have been removed again (sadly). By the sounds of it, if you create an app ID and NEVER use it, you can delete it, but if you use it at all, you are no longer allowed to do so. This is a useful link as well, as Xcode 5 does a lot of things for you now. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingProfiles/MaintainingProfiles.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH30-SW1

Comment: And the ability is back. Just click "Edit" button, scroll down to the bottom, then hit "Delete".

Comment: This comment is not about how. i don't know why it is recommended

Answer (score 78):

App IDs cannot be removed because once allocated they need to stay alive so that another App ID doesn't accidentally collide with a previously existing App ID.

Apple should however support hiding unwanted App IDs (instead of completely deleting them) to reduce clutter.

Comment: I think we should all email Apple at once letting them know how stupid and annoying it is that we cant hide these yet!

Comment: i believe apple knows how frustrated we are long time ago. they just don't give a gosh darnit.

Comment: @OMGPOP +1 for the double euphemism

Comment: Please check this stack link. we CAN delete the app by . go to AppId Edit > Delete.
  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24008521/2098690

Comment: The app may be removed from itunesConnest, and then its associated budle identifier, once it is at least one time approved by apple. The app never approved, but submitted to itunesconnect cannot be removed at all. So, since then it becomes a trash.

Answer (score 61):

In the iOS Dev Center developer navigate to "Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles > iOS Apps > Identifiers > App IDs"

Find the app id you wish to delete, highlight it and select "Settings". At the bottom of the resulting screen there is a "Delete" button.

---

Previously the only way to do this was to use a Safari & Chrome extension written by [Simon Whitaker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/263871/simon-whitaker)

[app-id-sanity downloads](https://github.com/simonwhitaker/app-id-sanity/downloads)

It gives you an "Active" checkbox next to all your App IDs and allows you to relabel them to alter how they appear in the App ID drop-down when creating new provisioning profiles.

Comment: Great Add-on - brings some sanity:-)

Comment: For Chrome, just install from the [Chrome Web Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dleofkjfblmgcedmhdankbcmhonjndne)

Comment: Delete button is grayed out

Comment: I found my delete button is grayed out as well. I am wondering if some one had experience to delete App IDs

Comment: your account must be agent account. If you isn't it, even you are admin, you cannot see the delete button

Comment: Works in November 2017!

Answer (score 25):

- As of Apr 2013, it is possible to delete App IDs.
- As of Sep 2013, it is impossible to delete App IDs again after the big outage.
  I hope Apple will put it back.
- As of mid 2014, it is possible to delete App IDs again. However, you can't delete id of apps existing in the App Store.

Answer (score 6):

Delete application IDs is allowed. Make sure you deleted all certificates, APNS certs and provisioning profiles associated with your application. Then go to **Identitifies** --> **App IDs**, select the application ID, **Edit** and **Delete** button should be enabled.

Comment: How to multi-select the junk AppId created due to Automatic Provisioning checkbox , doing one by one in pain

Answer (score 2):

As @AlexanderN pointed out, you can now delete App IDs.

1. In your **Member Center** go to the **Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles** section.
2. Go to **Identifiers** folder.
3. Select the App ID you want to delete and click **Settings**
4. Scroll down and click **Delete**.

Comment: there is no 'setting' and 'delete' option

Comment: yes, you are able to press delete button, but then appears a warning: 'app id cannot be removed, because it is used by app store':)

Answer (score 2):

When I do what explains some answers:

[image: Screen Shot 1]

The result is:

[image: Screen Shot 2]

So, anybody can explain really really how to delete an old App ID?

My opinion is: **Apple does not let you remove them.** I suppose it is a way to maintain the traceability or the historical of the published.

And of course: application is no longer available in the App Store. It was available (in the past), yes.