# iOS Provisioning: How do I discard unwanted app ids and provisioning profiles?

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile, app-id

So, my list of app ids and provisioning profiles is extremely cluttered in need of some serious culling.

How do I discard old unwanted app ids and provisioning profiles?

Thanks,
Doug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly there is no way to delete app ids. I don't know why Apple prevents this.

You can delete provisioning profiles though. Go to the Provisioning screen, check the ones you wish to delete, and click on the `Remove Selected` button.

**Update**:

April 7, 2013 - Apple made a major change to the provisioning portal website. You can now delete most app ids. But for some reason, not all app ids can be deleted. In my own case, I have three app ids that can't be deleted. I was able to delete several others though.

Comment: Now you can delete App IDs. It has been answered here [Removing App ID from Developer Connection](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15898322/713370)

Answer (score 0):

You can delete provisioning profiles in iOS Provisioning Portal. You cannot delete an app ID.