# Can't delete App ID from Apple Developer Center

Tags: ios, iphone

I've seen where Apple has changed the Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles page of the iOS dev center, and read this question/answer here on stack: [Removing App ID from Developer Connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/996477/removing-app-id-from-developer-connection)

But I'm unable to delete an App ID/IDs that are several years old that I would like removed. The 'Delete' button is greyed out/not enabled.

Can someone help me at all? I've tried multiple browsers and clearing my cache to no avail. Thank you in advance!

Screenshot: [image]

Comment: Does it work for other your App IDs? I can delete mine without problem...

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The rule is that if an App ID that has ever been submitted with an App to the store, it cannot be deleted (even if it was not accepted). App IDs that have not yet been used to submit apps can be freely deleted.

Checkout this thread on Apple Developer Forums (You'll need to be logged in to view):

https://devforums.apple.com/message/801353

Comment: Is there any methods that I can delete all unused App IDs at once?

Comment: @Dan How long take a time to reused my bundle id in new developer accounts?

Comment: @Dan, Please check this error message "The App ID 'xxxxx' appears to be in use by the App Store, so it can not be removed at this time".

Comment: Even an app that was never submitted and deleted from Itunes?

Comment: @FilipeBezerradeSousa, same question? Did you able to delete it?

Comment: No @Hemang, it can't be deleted. We're able only to change the status to Removed

Comment: That link no longer works to https://devforums.apple.com/message/801353 even when logged in.

Answer (score 9):

Make sure that the ID is not in use anymore. For me, the delete button is greyed out for those IDs which are in current use by an app in iTunes Connect, even if that app has just been prepared and has not yet been submitted to the App Store!

Comment: The App ID's I want to remove are not in use anymore and have been removed from iTunes Connect ages ago, I'm really lost as to why this isn't working.

Comment: *not anymore*...  In this case this may be due to the fact that apple keeps old builds to enable users who previously purchased your app to restore their purchases. These builds will use the ID of course and hence Apple can't allow to free the ID up. I'm speculating though and can't confirm this theory because all my apps I ever submitted are still available in the App Store. Maybe someone else?

Comment: One of the App ID's I want to remove was never approved for the App Store, so that can't be it I don't think.

Comment: I was able to look at the JSON response for trying to manually delete the app by pasting the link into the URL bar, and it said this:  `"resultString": "There is no iOS App ID with ID 'JK24X5ZR21' on this team."`

Answer (score 7):

The delete button is back (June 2014)!

- go to Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles
- open App IDs,
- select your App,
- click Edit
- click Delete

I was able to delete all unwanted apps (except those that were once in the app store) from the updated member center today.

Comment: So I have delete the unwanted app from AppStoreConnect too, still can't delete the AppID from DeveloperCentre, how to delete those unwanted AppIDs?

Answer (score 1):

If your App is in the AppStore or in the Submission Process, you can't delete the AppID. First  you have to disable the App from AppStore.

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to delete an apparently unused App ID because there was a provisioning profile associated with this ID. once removed, I was able to delete the ID successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Yup its in gray color but click on that button you will get popUp to delete  your appId.

You can go with Toastor's answer.

But if your are not able to delete unused AppId then you  just try to delete in different system because i also faced same situation and that issue was only with my system.

Comment: Have you been able to delete an ID which has been in current use that way? I'd think the button is grayed out for a reason and that being able to click it anyway is a bug, not the button being greyed out...

Answer (score 0):

ios Mobile Application created on the app store before going app live can't delete the bundle ID created once on the apple developer account :

https://developer.apple.com/help/app-store-connect/create-an-app-record/remove-an-app

[image]