# iOS App ID - Delete button greyed out in Developer Portal

Tags: ios, enterprise, provisioning-profile

In the iOS Developer Portal, I am trying to delete some of my old app IDs. The delete button for some reason is greyed out! And I have no idea why!

Before anyone points the obvious, YES, I have tried clicking 'Delete' and nothing happens. We have an Enterprise license and I am logged in as the team agent.

I also noticed that for each App ID, I can see an 'Edit' and 'Delete' button.

In the Apple documentation, the 'Edit' and 'Delete' buttons don't exist, instead there is a 'Settings' button (refer to screens below).

Why put a delete button on the damn thing if it doesn't work? Garr! Does anyone know how to get around this?

**WHAT I SEE:** 
[image]

**APPLE DOCS**

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingCertificatesandProvisioningAssets/MaintainingCertificatesandProvisioningAssets.html
[image]

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/996477/removing-app-id-from-developer-connection

Answer (score 0):

Delete also the provisioning profiles that are using it, and may double check if in ITC there is an application that is still using it.

Comment: Is that absolutely necessary? Unfortunately some of the App Ids I want to delete share the same provisioning profiles as the App Ids I want to keep.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't , it is just a guess

Comment: I deleted all my profiles and unfortunately I am still unable to delete the app ids. It was worth a shot :)

Comment: Really sorry, I can't find any other reason :-(